# defaultColDef is not applied in ag grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

i am working on an angular application and i want to apply default options to all fields so i used defaultColDef but apparently it's not working here's my code :

```
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;justify-self: center;"
    (filterChanged)="handleFilterChanged($event)"
    [rowData]="plaintes"
    
    domLayout="autoHeight"
    [columnDefs]="displayedColumns"
    [defaultColDef]="default"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

```
 default: ColDef = {
    filter: true,
    filterParams : {filterOptions : ['equals'] , suppressAndOrCondition: true}
  };
```

PS : when i move these values from defaultcoldef to the field it works